# How to avoid duplicate document indexing in Lucene 6.0

Tags: java, lucene, spring-batch

I am creating a Lucene Index for values got from database. I have set Index `OpenMode` as `OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND`.

Index creation step is part of a Spring Batch Job.

My understanding is that when I run job for the first time, indexing might take a while but when I rerun the job again for **same unchanged source data**, it should be fast because document is already there so **UPDATE OR INSERT** has not be performed.

But for my case, subsequent indexing attempts for **same unchanged source data** gets slower and slower.

Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731671/lucene-how-to-add-document-without-duplication) says that it will be handled automatically **based on a term.**

I am not sure as how to I define the term in my case to handle this?

Below is my sample code,

```
        public Integer createIndex(IndexWriter writer, String str, LuceneIndexerInputVO luceneInputVO) throws Exception {
            Integer count = 0;
            Document d = null;
            txtFieldType.setTokenized(false);
            strFieldType.setTokenized(false);

            List<IndexVO> indexVO = null;

            indexVO = jdbcTemplate.
                    query(Constants.SELECT_FROM_TABLE1, 
                            new Object[] {luceneInputVO.getId1(), luceneInputVO.getId2(), str}, 
                            new IndexRowMapper());

            while (!indexVO.isEmpty()) {
                d = new Document();
                d.add(getStringField(Constants.ID, String.valueOf(luceneInputVO.getId())));
                .....
                ....
                writer.addDocument(d);
                indexVO.remove(indexVO.get(count));
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

What should I change in above code to not perform indexing when there is no change in source data?

I am a beginner to Lucene and not sure as how to define that `Term` which would decide about duplicity.

I don't want indices to be recreated and I wish new `Document` to be skipped ( don't do anything ) if exactly same `Document` already exists in Index.

**EDIT -** I asked a long question but after reading SO for few Lucene related questions, I realize that I am simply asking for **incremental indexing** approach while focusing on duplicate avoidance provided a document represents a row of a RDBMS table having a primary key. If DB row is changed, update document otherwise not and add docs for new rows.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462652/lucene-how-to-perform-an-incremental-indexing-and-avoid-delete-and-redo),[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450416/incremental-indexing-lucene)

Comment: `id` field identify a document. If there is no unique id, then you need to check with your own logic before import.

Comment: how do I code the `id` of `Document`. In this case, all the `Fields` combined identify a `Document`. I guess, I need to define something like  `new Term(...,...)`

Comment: No, if you are using SolrJ, to specify id of a document, just create a `SolrInputDocument`, and set id field via `doc.setField("id", ...);`

Comment: I am not using `SolrJ` but Lucene Core , `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
  </dependency>'

Comment: With bare `Lucene`, you can define a field `id` as the unique key, which should come from your data model, e.g primary key in your database. When update a document, need delete the old doc by id, and insert a new doc. I suggest you to use SolrJ, which has feature like delta import that would save a lot of work.

Comment: In addition to unique key ( which would simply say if document already exists or not ), I need to compare full doc content to new document ( to decide if replace or not ). If incoming doc is exact copy of existing doc, do nothing.

Comment: What I meant to say is there might be changes or no changes in document for non - primary key fields too and I have to decide accordingly if to update document or not.

Comment: Use a timestamp field to record the last modification, thus decide whether need to update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have verified that in Lucene 6.0.0 , `IndexWriter.updateDocument(Term term,Document doc);` adds a new Document if document doesn't already exist and updates existing Document if found as per `term`.

For my requirement, I defined a `key` field which is basically a concatenation of all other value fields for `Document`. This way `key` identifies content wise duplicates i.e. for two documents having same `key` means that documents are content wise duplicates.

I construct `term` to be passed to `IndexWriter.updateDocument(Term term,Document doc);` on this `key` value and just calling `IndexWriter.updateDocument(Term term,Document doc);` instead of `IndexWriter.addDocument(Document doc)` solves issue.